# Java-LDAP Issue

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to connect to my company ldap programmatically via java on windows. However I end up with this exception.

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C09018A, comment: The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, vece ]
```

Here is my code for the same

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://url");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "distinguished_name");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        // env.put("javax.security.sasl.qop", "auth-conf"); //tried this too but same exception
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);


    }
```

Tried googling the issue but got different responses to SSL. Tried them yet no avail. Any suggestions ?

Comment: for PROVIDER_URL - you are specifying proper url, right?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.dirwiz.com/kb/346

Comment: So use TLS or don't use 'simple'.

Comment: @Batty Yes I am. Just couldnt post it here.

Comment: @EJP Tried using TLS. Getting this "javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: tls"

Comment: @Jens Thanks will take a look.

Comment: TLS is a transport protocol, not an authentication method. You use TLS by specifying an 'ldaps:` URL, possibly with a different port, depending on how your LDAP server is configured. You need to look things up, rather than just guess.